# Python: Using my heap in a priority queue implementation

Tags: python, heap, priority-queue, binary-heap

I am having real trouble using my custom-made heap class functions to be used in my Priority Queue class. I am having trouble on what functions from my heap class to use for my "enqueue", "dequeue", "front" and "size" functions for my PriorityQueue. I know for "enqueue" I need to use my insert function, but I don't know how to go about this because I have a priority. Could someone help me out what I need to do in order to make my PriorityQueue class to use the functions from my Heap class in order to work properly? I have been stuck on this for awhile and I keep finding answers that include using the built in python functions such as queue and heapq.

class Heap(object):

```
    def __init__(self, items=None):

        '''Post: A heap is created with specified items.'''

        self.heap = [None]
        if items is None:
            self.heap_size = 0
        else:
            self.heap += items
            self.heap_size = len(items)
            self._build_heap()

    def size(self):

        '''Post: Returns the number of items in the heap.'''

        return self.heap_size

    def _heapify(self, position):

        '''Pre: Items from 0 to position - 1 satisfy the Heap property.
       Post: Heap Property is satisfied for the entire heap.'''

        item = self.heap[position]
        while position * 2 <= self.heap_size:
            child = position * 2
            # If the right child, determine the maximum of two children.
            if (child != self.heap_size and self.heap[child+1] > self.heap[child]):
                child += 1
            if self.heap[child] > item:
                self.heap[position] = self.heap[child]
                position = child
            else:
                break
        self.heap[position] = item

    def delete_max(self):

        '''Pre: Heap property is satisfied
       Post: Maximum element in heap is removed and returned. '''

        if self.heap_size > 0:
            max_item = self.heap[1]
            self.heap[1] = self.heap[self.heap_size]
            self.heap_size -= 1
            self.heap.pop()
            if self.heap_size > 0:
                self._heapify(1)
            return max_item

    def insert(self, item):

        '''Pre: Heap Property is Satisfied.
       Post: Item is inserted in proper location in heap.'''

        self.heap_size += 1
        # extend the length of the list.
        self.heap.append(None)
        position = self.heap_size
        parent = position // 2
        while parent > 0 and self.heap[parent] < item:
            # Move the item down.
            self.heap[position] = self.heap[parent]
            position = parent
            parent = position // 2
        # Puts the new item in the correct spot.
        self.heap[position] = item

    def _build_heap(self):

        ''' Pre: Self.heap has values in 1 to self.heap_size
           Post: Heap property is satisfied for entire heap. '''

        # 1 through self.heap_size.

        for i in range(self.heap_size // 2, 0, -1): # Stops at 1.
            self._heapify(i)

    def heapsort(self):

        '''Pre: Heap Property is satisfied.
           Post: Items are sorted in self.heap[1:self.sorted_size].'''

        sorted_size = self.heap_size

        for i in range(0, sorted_size -1):
            # Since delete_max calls pop to remove an item, we need to append a dummy value to avoid an illegal index.
            self.heap.append(None)
            item = self.delete_max()
            self.heap[sorted_size - i] = item
```

So this is working but like I previously stated I am having trouble on how to make a priority queue out of this? I know asking for code is wrong, but I'm desperate could anyone help me out here? I have the basic rundown on what I want my priority code to do..

```
#PriorityQueue.py
from MyHeap import Heap


class PriorityQueue(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.heap = None

    def enqueue(self, item, priority):
        '''Post: Item is inserted with specified priority in the PQ.'''
        self.heap.insert((priority, item))

    def first(self):
    '''Post: Returns but does not remove the highest priority item from the PQ.'''
        return self.heap[0]

    def dequeue(self):
    '''Post: Removes and returns the highest priority item from the PQ.'''
    if self.heap is None:
        raise ValueError("This queue is empty.")
    self.heap.delete_max()

    def size(self):
    '''Post: Returns the number of items in the PQ.'''
        return self.size
```

This is what I got so far but I do not know if it is entirely correct. Could anyone help me out?

I edited my code to the most current version of it.

Comment: Are you experiencing a specific problem? The best way to figure out if code is correct is to test it. At face value, though, it looks like dequeue isn't returning the highest priority item like it says, and is instead just deleting it. And obviously first still isn't implemented (hint: it's a one-liner).

Comment: would I need to make a __init__ function? something like this? `def __init__(self):   self.head = None` and then for the front do this? `def first(self): return self.head[0]` ?

Comment: You're totally on the right track, but why do you need to have a self.head? You've already got self.heap, and the maximum value can only be in one specific location within the heap... (an init function is generally a good thing for all classes to have though - I'm not entirely sure how you're initializing self.heap without one)

Comment: @seaotternerd Okay I think I understand what you mean. I edited my code could you see if that looks right to you so far?

Comment: Yes, that looks perfect for `first()`. You'll want to add something similar to dequeue, so that you can return the item that you removed. Also, it's probably simpler to not maintain a separate size variable for the PriorityQueue class, when you could just use the heap's `size()` method instead.

Comment: @seaotternerd So in my enqueue function I added the following, see code above, but now I'm absolutely confused on what function to use because none of them would make sense except for delete_max. But I have no idea what should go in the parenthesis's..

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. Checking the size in dequeue is a good idea. I just meant that you should call `heap.size()` rather than having a `self.size variable`. You're also right that you should call `delete_max()` (which doesn't look like it takes any arguments, so you shouldn't put anything in the parentheses). You just need to save the current maximum value before you call `delete_max()` and then return it.

Comment: @seaotternerd Would you suggest making a separate function in the MyHeap class that finds the max value and then call that in my dequeue? Or is there a simpler option.

Comment: You can find the maximum value exactly the way you found it in the `first()` method. No need for a whole additional method, since it's already a one-liner, and a pretty short one at that.

Comment: So would I call just the front method? I'm sorry I'm really having trouble with this. Thanks for bearing with me through this whole thing I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not seeing a front() method. Do you mean first ()? That would work! Just store the return in a variable and return that.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH for your help. If there was any way to pay you I would. Weird problem how would I go about making an iterator for this so I can print out what is in my queue?

Comment: You're welcome! Because comments aren't guaranteed to stick around, and StackOverflow seeks to be a lasting resource, I summarized this series of hints into an answer. I also included some comments about an iterator at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is presumably homework, all I can do is give hints, which is often easier done as comments. Since this ended up being a fairly thorough series of hints I'm summarizing them as an answer here.

For the most part, methods in your `PriorityQueue` class will map to methods you've already implemented in your Heap class:

- `PriorityQueue.enqueue()` maps pretty easily to Heap.insert()
- `PriorityQueue.first()` does not have a corresponding heap method, but can still be implemented in one line. You just need to return the maximum value, which will always be at a specific place in your heap.
- `PriorityQueue.dequeue()` is a little more complicated. It needs to save the value of the top item first so that it can return it after calling `heap.delete_max()`
- The heap class already has a `size()` method, which `PriorityQueue.size()` can call, instead of maintaining a separate size variable within the `PriorityQueue` class.

Additionally, you need an init function, This should create a new Heap object that will be maintained by the class.

In order to make an iterator, you'll need to make a new class. It will need to maintain an integer variable (let's call it `self.index`), indicating its current place in the queue. You'll also want a method that increases `self.index` and returns the value that was at the previous index location. That should be about it.